# Extremely slow connection with a Broadcom BCM4313 wireless card

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, 14.04

Recently upgraded into 14.04 from 12.04 using ubuntu update manager. After the system restart, the browser is not showing the web pages(although the wireless network is present/connected and running). I would say the internet is extremely extremely extremely slow, because few bookmarked sites showed some bits of site contents 1/1000 times. And the the loading circle symbol turns to orange most of the time, anyhow displays nothing.

wireless driver(proprietary) : Broadcom BCM4313 wireless driver
lenovo G580 laptop
intel i5

- I am not in a situation to connect my lap using the network cable. So looking forward to alternate solutions
- [Here is the link](http://pastebin.com/z5c4mQuQ) to the current wireless status/information of my system.
- [Here is the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frNSs.jpg) to the NetHogs results and the browser loading window(which shows the page title and loading symbol turns orange). My internet connection peeks 580KB/s in windows and 12.04

Any help is much appreciated

**UPDATE** : Connected to the network using USB tethering from my phone, and works like a charm. Which means wired connection is still on. Done some 20KB of update and still the wifi stays the same. It feels so great(relieved) posting here from my 14.04. The pain is still there, but i will live.

### The final Update

A special thanks to @Wild Man for solving this nightmare of mine. And to you guys who took the effort to give a helping hand. YOU GUYS ARE THE BEST

Comment: Copy and paste this command in the terminal (ctrl+alt+t)`wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script`
It will download a script and create a file named wireless-info.tar.gz in your home folder with wireless information so we can see the condition of your wireless at this time and the Mac address, WPA key and WEP key are removed for your security,paste contents of the wireless-info.tar.gz file at http://pastebin.com/. 
No internet
<]http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Comment: Thanks for the replay @WildMan . Here is the link to the result
http://pastebin.com/z5c4mQuQ

Comment: i have the same problem on lenovo u410. Wireless is detected but it never connects. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4m8hfFqD Best regards, Adri

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -rv wl
sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac
```

if there are any errors complete the rest of the commands anyway.

We may have to unblacklist some modules if the purge command does not do it for us.

Comment: You know what? i love you ma man. This is like some kind of God's hand, and definitely you are the God. You should be proud of yourself, making someone's life this happy deserves much appreciation. Heart felt thanks to you man; and i love this community. YOU GUYS ROCK

Comment: Don't follow these instructions if you have BCM4352 [14e4:43b1]. It removed the detection of the wifi device from Ubuntu.

Comment: The device that this answer pertains to is  BCM4313 and not 14e4:43b1, so always make sure the commands you run pertains to your device.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight possibility that something in the background might be hogging your bandwidth. So for checking that, download a tool called 'nethogs'. It is a tool which displays that what application is using how much bandwidth along with the process ID.

To install nethogs on your Ubuntu, open the terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

This will install the tool in your Ubuntu.

Now to access nethogs type in the terminal.

```
sudo nethogs wlan0
```

This will show you that which application is using how much bandwidth. This should help determining that whether it is a driver problem or simply some application hogging your bandwidth.

Do this and tell me what you see.

Comment: @Sangeeth Khatri thanks for the answer. As there was no internet in the first place, downloaded the .deb file using windows [and here are the results](http://imgur.com/a/w1geY#0). I can guarantee that my internet connection peeks 580KB/s in windows and 12.04

Comment: Your internet is connected because if it wasn't connected then you would not be able to see the nethogs screen at the first place. So the bug actually is what you reported it as, that you are not getting bandwidth at the first place. I once had this problem but it was router related, more specifically MTU related, but since this bug has been caused after upgrading the OS, therefore router related bugs are out of the question.

I would do my research and try to help if I got any relevant information but don't count on it.

Comment: Yeah the router is shared with more than 10 people, and it works fine for them and for my windows partition. am desperately looking forward to that help

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with this after I installed 14.04, but didn't think it was related to Ubuntu. I unplugged my modem and then plugged it back in, and it started working again. I am probably going to get laughed out, but it's still worth a try.

Comment: And you think i didn't try that!; and for the 1000th time of replugging it still the same :'(