# Issue with Broadcom 4313 - wireless card very very slow in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have upgraded to 14.04. When I was in 12.04 I got the drivers from Broadcom website. But, now I can't get that for 14.04. I am just a user and I don't have much knowledge about ubuntu.

I tried the answer from [Extremely slow connection with a Broadcom BCM4313 wireless card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450049/extremely-slow-connection-with-a-broadcom-bcm4313-wireless-card)

But, my wireless doesn't work properly. Very very slow at around 5KB/s. When I connect to ethernet I get around 400KB/s

Please be little elaborate so that I can follow your guide.

Answer (score 0):

Strange... but I did absolutely the opposite to recommendations of @Wild Man:

i've installed  **bcmwl-kernel-source** and removed **bcma** & **brcmsmac**, and i got my normal speed :-\

```
[~]> lsmod | grep wl                                                                                                                            
        wl             4207846  0    
        lib80211       14381    2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip  
        cfg80211       484040   2 wl,mac80211  

[~]> lspci  
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)   

[~]> lsb_release -a                                                                                                                             
    Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

[~]> uname -a                                                                                                                                   
Linux martin 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```